# How to search a webpage using selenium by any of the keywords inputted?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium in python. I am searching the supreme [website](https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/t-shirts) by keywords using Xpath as such:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Supreme Time Tee')]"))).click()
```

My question is how would I search keywords for any text and skip until it finds it? For example, I struggle to grab the t shirt labeled "Dragon Tee Heather Grey" that is split into two a href link tags "Dragon Tee" and "Heather Grey".

I want to be able to click either element but I am not sure how to construct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this xpath:

```
 //a[contains(text(),'Dragon Tee')] /parent::div/following-sibling::*/a[contains(text(),'Dusty')]
```

Comment: I didn't word my question well, but is there a way to search the entire body by keywords instead of specific tags?

Comment: do you mean this //*[contains(@class,'products view-all category  us')]/descendant::*

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to solve this by looking for sibling tags. For example, if you want to find the Dragon Tee Heather Grey link, you can use this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[a/text() = "Dragon Tee"]/following-sibling::div[a/text() = "Heather Grey"]')
```