# How to find specific product if their are multiple products with the same name using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am making a supreme bot and I want it to find a specific product on https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts when it drops.
But their are multiple products with the same name for example when I write

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Cutout Logo Crewneck Violet").click()
```

It dosent find it but if I change the Cutout Logo Crewneck Violet to just violet it clicks on the violet one. Or if I take out the violet from the Cutour Logo Crewneck it clicks on the first one that it finds which is not the violet one.

I think its because the color and the name are on separate divs but I'm not sure.

```
<li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" 
href="/shop/sweatshirts/al1qigtzr/iki14srab"><img width="150" height="150" 
src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/188962/vi/hZiiM3_KhGM.jpg" alt="Hziim3 khgm">
<div class="sold_out_tag">sold out</div></a><div class="product-name"><a 
class="name-link" href="/shop/sweatshirts/al1qigtzr/iki14srab">Cutout Logo 
Crewneck</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link"
href="/shop/sweatshirts/al1qigtzr/iki14srab">Violet</a></div></div></li>
```

I want it to find the product by the name because supreme products sell out fast and I dont have time to get the xpath of the product.

Comment: I have answered this exact question before I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354961/how-to-search-a-webpage-using-selenium-by-any-of-the-keywords-inputted/61355482#61355482

Comment: The product is unique or there is a chance to have more than 1 with the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. I would use `.text` of WebElements in order to find a match. You can just collect text inside the elements (`divs` which include the product name and color) and then among these elements find the one that has your desired product name and color.

Try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/sweatshirts')

# Collect all products per page
products = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.inner-article')

# Input your search query here
search = 'Cutout Logo Crewneck Violet'

search_words = search.split()
found_product = False

# Search for a match by text inside product WebElements
for p in products:
    if all(search_word in p.text for search_word in search_words):
        found_product = p

found_product.click() if found_product else print('No product found')
```

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much your solution is working but how can I make if it doesn't find the product refresh the page until it finds it.

Comment: I would add a loop before collecting products, after each iteration of a loop, add a condition: `if not found_product: driver.refresh() else: pass`. And you probably need to add a `sleep(60)` before making refresh, so your script waits for 1 min before checking again.